# How to create filter to find data of exactly n number of words in a google sheet in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

By n number of words I mean the words differentiated by sapce

Eg. If it is Tata Consulting Services then it has 3 words. And if it is Tata Consultancy Services Pvt Ltd then it has 5 words

Answer (score -1):

you can try using google sheets formula  as added below. it counts the number of spaces in the cell and according to it, add 1 to that number to get the words number.

e.g cell value='Test Data'. The number of space is 1 and so adding 1 to it gives word count of 2.

```
=ADD(countif (A1, " "),1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shabnam, but it is not giving the result I need.

If there are 3 rows in a column A in the sheet. Say Following are the data in it: Tata Consulting Solutions, Harvard university and New York Times.

Now when I run the filter, it should show just Tata Consulting Solutions and and New York Times in Column A in the two rows.

Thanks again for your time on this

Comment: Can you share a dummy sheet with data stating the exact sitauation?

Comment: Here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zOoidU_Sm01O1kR6Rg-MeQuUJhsTebaF-xPHorj2ZkQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Shabnam we can ignore the columns that's not important, we need to process only the data from Column A. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: i have created a filter with query formula to get data with n=2 number of words